# "It's X here." or "This is X."

Tags: phrase-usage

I received some promotional email this morning.  It began:

Hi customer, It's Bernard Martin here.  Wouldn't you love to be able to..."

I thought the standard opening was "This is Bernard Martin."

I understand the "it" is a dummy subject but to me it seems weird to refer to a person as "it."

Are things changing?  Is "It's X, here." becoming acceptable or has it always been acceptable and in wide-spread use, and I just never leave my cave?

Comment: This is a sort of telephone conversation idiom.  Though normally it would be "Hi customer, Bernard Martin here." -- no "It's".  This is not particularly common, and likely is losing popularity as more communications flow away from phones to email and text.

Answer (score -1):

> [It's only me](http://www.bbcamerica.com/shows//blog/2014/02/recap-life-gets-bazaar-at-downton-abbey).

Catchphrase of Lady Isobel Crawley of TV's Downton Abbey.

That said I wouldn't recommend taking English usage cues from internet spam.  TV is beter for those of us who stick to our caves.